# Modern News Gallery Bug(s)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, bug

Running into two different things that seem like bugs when using the News Gallery web part in a SharePoint Online Modern Communication Site:

Internet Explorer: Within  IE, the News Gallery does not show the title of the article in the view, and also on first load it shows the correct URL for each article when scrolling but after a while it reverts to showing/opening a single article when any of the five are clicked.

Chrome: Chrome correctly shows the title, but has the same article selection bug.

For more detail on the selection bug, if I have 5 articles in the gallery, sometimes when scrolling through, it shows each article correctly (i.e. "Test Article 1" and "Test Article 2" will be visible and selectable) but then seems to break and the only "Test Article 1" is selectable even though I can scroll through all 5 and see article titles.

I have not seen anything from Microsoft on this, and not many user complaints, so maybe I'm doing something wrong on my end?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my SharePoint Online communication site, I cannot reproduce your issue either in IE or in Chrome.

Do you mean when you click the other four News posts, it cannot direct to the relevant news page? You can narrow your issue as following:

1. Clear the browser cache and check again.
2. Where did you add the News web part? Try to create a new page and add the News web part, then check again.
3. Create some new News page and check if they have the same issue.

Comment: Let me be more detailed step-by-step: 1) Load into my SharePoint Online Communications page which has a News Gallery with 5 items in it. 2) On initial load, I can look at all 5 items and it goes to the correct news article. 3) When I hit the arrow through all 5 and back to the start, it is stuck on the 5th article for the URL (so it shows article 1 image but the URL/link is for the 5th article.